# npm serial-port get the output to react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, socket.io, serial-port

I am developing a weighing application, which reads Serial port data and displays on the client. I got the NodeJS script for reading the serial port,

my **serial.js** , this gives me the weight from my weighing machine as a stream

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const ReadLine = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;

//Defining the Serial port
var port  = new SerialPort("COM1", {
    baudRate:9600,
});

//the serial port parser
const parser = new ReadLine();
port.pipe(parser);

//read data from serial port
parser.on("data", (line) => console.log(line));
```

How can I get the output from this script to my following react component?

```
<Input
id="weight"
element="textarea"
type="textarea"
label="Weight"
onInput={inputHandler}
/>
```

And what steps do I need to take to make it work online? I heard about websockets. Please put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

** This is a simple code and need to complete it **

server side (Nodejs) :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    port = 8888;

//Server start
server.listen(port, () => console.log('on port' + port))

//user server
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', onConnection);

var connectedSocket = null;
function onConnection(socket){
    connectedSocket = socket;
}


const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline; 
const usbport = new SerialPort('COM4');  
const parser = usbport.pipe(new Readline()); 
parser.on('data', function (data) {
    io.emit('serialdata', { data: data });
});
```

Client side (React):

```
import React from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8888');
    //this.socket.open();
    this.socket.on('serialdata', (data) => {
      // we get settings data and can do something with it
      this.setState({
        settings: data,
      })
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```